# cmd batch processing:how to compress all dirs under one dir to another dir?

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I want to compress all dirs and all files under one dir to another dir.
such as I want to compress all dirs in d:\test to E:\backup

```
D:\test\testdir1
D:\test\testdir2
D:\test\testfile3
```

after compressing the dirs,I can get the zip file in E:\backup

```
E:\backup\testdir1.zip
E:\backup\testdir2.zip
E:\backup\testfile3.zip
```

I know in cmd command,I can compress through the "zip" command.
Like this

```
zip -r   e:\backup\testdir1.zip  d:\test\testdir1
```

But I don't know how to loop the all dirs and file under D:\test.
So who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but if you use a batch file, it would be somethink like:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b D:\test') do zip %%f E:\backup\%%f.zip
```

else

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b D:\test') do zip %f E:\backup\%f.zip
```

Comment: `for /d  %%f in (d:\test\*) do zip  e:\backup\%%f.zip   %%f `but the %%f is `d:\test\test1dir`,how to make the %%f  is `test1.dir`

Comment: finally,I can through `cd the target dir` to zip file in order to make the dir path  not in zip file.thanks